# what is the exact relation between Dedekind tessellation and modular group

Tags: tessellations, modular-group, reflection-group

In the wiki for the [Modular Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group) the group ($\Gamma$) is described as a $(2,3,\infty)$.

The page has a diagram for "a typical fundamental domain for the action of $\Gamma$ on the upper half-plane". I don't see how the fundamental region applies for $\Gamma$ itself...maybe for a subgroup might make more sense.

So which of these two diagrams is more accurate for the action of $\Gamma$?

The first one does look like the (regular) Dedekind tessellation, but the second makes more sense in terms of the action : I see rotations of order $2,3,\infty$ in second but only $3,\infty$ in the first.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first one is correct. The second is correct but for a different group (a Coxeter/triangle group).

Comment: The wiki says that $\Gamma = (2,3,\infty)$ which is a Coxeter group...is there a mixup?

Comment: They are using the notation $(p,q,r)$ for von Dyck groups, not triangle groups. (Mistakenly, they call von Dyck group "rotational triangle groups.") You should be careful when blindly trusting Wikipedia.

Comment: who said I did. Anyway I still don't see anything of order 2 in the first diagram so I don't see its connection to $\Gamma$.

Comment: Look at the symmetry $z\mapsto -\bar z$ in the picture. It has order 2.

Comment: that's a reflection though and there are plenty of these...I'm looking for a rotation.

Comment: The standard involution is $-1/z$. It is a hyperbolic rotation.